How to decompose a simple $3\times3$ shear transformation into a rotation, scale, and rotation
Is there a simple way to decompose the following $3\times3$ shear matrix into the product of a
rotation, (non-uniform) scale, and another rotation? Or Perhaps
some other combination of rotations and scales?
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & b\\ 0 & 0 & c\end{array}\right]$$
I asked wolfram alpha to perform a (symbolic) SVD on this matrix and its gives me an unusable hairy answer.
Here is a specific example matrix
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 4
\end{array}\right]
$$
which (via SVD) can be decomposed into
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& U \Sigma V^T \\
U &=& \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.378424 & -0.83205 & -0.405571 \\
0.567635 & 0.5547 & -0.608357 \\
0.731154 & 0 & 0.682213
\end{array}\right] \\
\Sigma &=& \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
5.42741 & 0 & 0. \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.736999
\end{array}\right] \\
V &=& 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.0697245 & -0.83205 & -0.550301 \\
0.104587 & 0.5547 & -0.825451 \\ 
0.992069 & 0 & 0.125698
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray} 
$$
where $U$ and $V^T$ are orthonormal matrices (with positive determinant) and are thus rotations and $\Sigma$ is a (non-uniform)
scale matrix.
There may be other decompositions that can break this up into
different sequences of rotations and scales. I am using transformations of this form in a graphics applications that
requires each entity in the scene graph to be composed of a scale,
rotation, and a translation -- if this is not possible I can factor
the transforms and add several child entities. I don't want to add
another dependency that includes a numerical library for
computing the SVD if I can help it. The matrix looked simple enough
that I was hoping there was a more direct solution.

Rotations and scaling preserve angles but non-trivial shears do not; is that what you're asking?

This will require a non-uniform scale. Using SVD we can decompose this matrix into USV^T where U and V are orthonormal and S is a non-uniform scale. I hope there is no need to use a SVD programming library just for this simple case.

In my experience, unusable hairy answers are pretty common in linear algebra. I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang, what makes you think there is even such a decomposition? Such a dec9mposition would mean $|Av|/|v|$ is constant for all non-zero vectors $v.$ That seems unlikely to be true.

@ThomasAndrews The fact that any 3x3 transformation can be decomposable into some sequence of scales and rotations lets me know it is possible. SVD can give me a path to solve the problem but seems like too much work in this case (need to check for reflections i.e. negative scales, etc...)  I believe I can write this matrix as the the product of an x-shear, y-shear, and non-uniform scale. An x-shear (or y-shear) is decomposable into and rotation, scale, rotation (at least my intuition thinks so).

@wcochran that's not true. Shear transformations are not conformal but scaling and rotation are. So it's impossible to model a shear transformation with scaling and rotations.

@CyclotomicField One can not model a shear with a single rotation and scale, but we can decompose a shear into a rotation, non-uniform scale, and another rotation -- this exactly what the singular value decomposition (SVD) does. We can also decompose 2D shears into a rotation, scale, rotation using the techniques here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~djames/15-462/Fall03/assts/15-462-Fall03-wrAssign1-answer.pdf

Maybe you mean something different by "scales and rotations," but in the meaning I know for these terms, this is not true - not every matrix can be decomposed into scales and rotations, and SVD doesn't decompose into scales and rotations. Maybe you are treating all diagonal matrices as a scale?

If you want the singular value decomposition there is no way to avoid doing the work. It's a computationally difficult task even if you just want an approximation.

@AndrewD.Hwang I added an example where I factor the matrix into a rotate, scale, and rotation transformation which can be done with any 3x3 matrix.

@ThomasAndrews I added an example to show how SVD can be used and works for any 3x3 matrix. All diagonal matrices represent a non-uniform scale.

As you may have surmised, scaling to a mathematician generally refers to what you're calling "uniform" scaling, i.e., multiplication by a scalar. It might help to edit the first sentence of the question body, and the title, to clarify that "axial scaling" or "(multiplication by) a diagonal matrix" is meant? :)

So, scaling is just meant to be diagonal.

@ThomasAndrews a diagonal matrix will scale each coordinate independently. If all the diagonal entries are the same it is referred as a uniform scale. If any of the entries are negative then you may have a reflection as well. Here I desire any type of scale that avoids reflections. SVD is sufficient in this case with a few precautions.

@CyclotomicField I avoided a generalized solver -- see me solution below.

For this special case I describe a simple approach so I can
avoid a general SVD solver.
We can compute the SVD $A = U \Sigma V^T$ via eigen-analysis of
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  A^T A &=& V \Sigma^2 V^T \\
    &=& \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
          1 & 0 & a \\
          0 & 1 & b \\
          a & b & a^2 + b^2 + c^2
        \end{array}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The eigenvalues of $A^T A$ are
$$
  \{\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2\} = 
   \left\{ \frac{s + q}{2}, 1, \frac{s - q}{2} \right\}
$$
where $s = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1$ and $q = \sqrt{s^2 - 4c^2}.$
The corresponding eigenvectors are
$$
  \{ \mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2 \} =
   \left\{
     \left[\begin{array}{c} a\\ b\\ \lambda_0 - 1 \end{array} \right],
     \left[\begin{array}{c} -b\\ a\\ 0 \end{array} \right],
     \left[\begin{array}{c} a\\ b\\ \lambda_2 - 1 \end{array} \right]
   \right\}.
$$
We form the columns of $V$ from the normalized eigenvectors
$$
   V = \left[ \hat{\mathbf{e}}_0, 
              \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1, 
              \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\right]
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i = \frac{\mathbf{e}_i}{\| \mathbf{e}_i\|}.$
To avoid a reflection, if $|A| < 0$ then we negate the last column of $V.$
Our scale matrix is created from the singular values
$\sigma_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}:$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  \Sigma  &=& \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
          \sqrt{\lambda_0} & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & \sqrt{\lambda_1} & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & \sqrt{\lambda_2}
        \end{array}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Finally $U = A V \Sigma^{-1}$ which will only be a reflection
if $|A| = c - a < 0.$ Fortunately, in my use case, $c > a.$
Therefore $A$ can be factored into the rotation $U$, scale $\Sigma,$ and rotation $V^T.$
